# What are the options to detect a change on parameter between components and directives?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-services, angular2-components

How `myDirective` can be notify/noticed when the `componentText` parameter has changed?

How `my-component` can be notify/noticed when the `directiveText` parameter has changed?

**simple directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective {

  private directiveText: string;
}
```

**simple component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<div>my component template</div>`
})
export class MyComponent{

  private componentText: string;
}
```

I know I can add a service and subscribe to any change of that service, but is that the only way for doing that? Think about the situation when the directive is using the component as a template for example, meaning they know each other.

Comment: Did you try using OnChange interface?

Comment: Make `componentText` a setter.

Comment: I try them both, that it not helps. The component for example is being updated but the directive don't catch that change.

Comment: BTW notich componentText and directiveText are not Inputs